# Position an element regardless of other elements

Tags: css

So I want to position an element across two columns, but only start in the middle of the second column.

Is there a way to do this? The columns are established by divs. I believe it would have to do with positioning via z-index?

Comment: Yes, and use absolute positioning of that element. Details will depend on your code, which you have not included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put second column `position:relative` and the element which you want to put in between second column `position:absolute`, adjust top and left.